# Ask for a thing about multivariable concave function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose a multivariable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is concave and sufficiently smooth. We have:

$\|f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{x}_0)\|\le M\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0\|$ for some positive constant $M$.

If the $f$ is univariate, we know that $M$ is the absolute value of the slope of the tangent line at $\mathbf{x}_0$. But what is it for multivariable case, is there a special name in math given to it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: consider $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=x$. It then holds that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\le 17\cdot |x-x_0|$. It what sense is $17$ the slope of anything?

Comment: why not M=1? you know what I mean. And, if we take M=17, the inequality does not hold for all x.

Comment: I don't follow. $M$ may not exist at all (consider $f(x)=-x^2$ for instance). Do you assume that $M$ exists?

Comment: why $M$ does not exist for $-x^2$? It is a convex function and the slope of the tangent line on the parabola satisfies the inequality for the fixed $x_0$ and all other $x$.

Comment: I see the mistake in the post. I should add "absolute value of"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition of [Lipschitz continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity). $M$ is called the Lipschitz constant of $f$.

Comment: Great! So, is sufficiently smooth concave function a special case of Lipschitz continuous function?

Comment: The link I gave has examples and counter-examples.